# GWT alter HTML content

Tags: gwt, restlet

I've  a `GWT` project which is using `Restlet` instead of `GWT-RPC.`
It seems that to gain some `performance`, previous developers have created a mechanism which consist of having some java script variables in the HTML template, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var details = $$$DETAILS$$$;
 var categories = $$$CATEGORIES$$$;
</script>
```

where `$$$DETAILS$$$` and `$$$CATEGORIES$$$` would be replaced upon request of the page with some `JSON` by a class extending `org.restlet.Application.`

Now, the plan is to `refactor` this application and a first step is to remove `Restlet` and get back to `GWT-RPC`.

I assume this method with `javascript` variables is pretty ugly and we could do something way better with `asynchronous calls.` But in the mean time, I would like to find a way to modify the `HTML` produced by `GWT` upon request like it's being done right now with `Restlet`.
As I'm brand new to `GWT`, I must acknowledge that I'm a bit lost and I haven't find answers yet.

Do you see any way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to read object attributes in GWT, but the easier way I see is to use [gwtquery](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/). In your case:

```
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;
[...]

// Read an attribute from the window element
String details = $(window).prop("details");

// Set the html content of the element/s matching the css selector
$("cssSelector").html(details);
```